# I am not able to start Next.js and tailwind project with npm run dev

Tags: node.js, reactjs, compiler-errors, next.js, tailwind-css

I created a **next - tailwind** project by using `npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project` i am on **windows 7** in case you want to know so whenever I try to run my app using `npm run dev` it gives an error -

```
> @ dev E:\Coding Projects\React\googledocs
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at getChromeVersion (E:\Coding Projects\React\googledocs\node_modules\jest-worker\node_modules\supports-color\browser.js:5:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Coding Projects\React\googledocs\node_modules\jest-worker\node_modules\supports-color\browser.js:14:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at _supportsColor (E:\Coding Projects\React\googledocs\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:39:16)
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (E:\Coding Projects\React\googledocs\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:136:24)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-18T13_52_56_599Z-debug.log
```

Any Help will be appreciated **(•͈ᴗ•)**

Comment: my project name is googledocs and i did cd into it

Comment: yeah it is 11.0.1

Comment: ok i am trying that

Comment: sorry i cant do that as i am on windows 7 and LTS version is for 8.1 and above

Comment: I have v13.6.0 already in node.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the nodejs version. update nodejs to 14.17.0 , solved for me.